# Collecting the same email address in a Google Form

Tags: google-forms

Hopefully this isn't confusing.

I'm wondering if there's a way of using a preset email address instead of collecting users email addresses in a form.  Essentially, I'm looking for all the form responses to get sent to *one* email address which can then be forwarded to a specific place when needed.

Not sure if the prefilled URL will do this or not.

Comment: How are you sending the email?  Is it possible to use a value which is not part of the form?  This idea could be a column beyond the form responses or even a cell in a different sheet (tab).

Comment: I would like to use the google option to collect the email but have that already be filled out instead of typing in the same email

Comment: Row A could have a formula such as: `=ARRAYFUNCTION(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,IF(ROW(A1:A)=1, "SEND EMAIL TO", "MYEMAIL@MYCOMAIN.com")))`  (note that this is untested)  This would put the same email in every row where there is a response.

Comment: Why is the "Googl Script" included in the title? Please show what do you searched/researched as it's required by [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the get a pre-filled link option for this, provided you create your own question asking for the email address instead of the google made one.

You can even turn on data validation for your created question to make them type in a valid looking address.

Comment: Is there a way to make the google email address question preset to a specific email address though? I just want the email "here's what we go from you" blah blah but for all of those to go to one email. although now that I type this I wonder about just using the notification after every response would work too...

Comment: I am assuming you want to mail merge pre-filled forms. Google uses query strings like: entry.700706906=me@example.com to send out a mail merge you will need to use google scripts you will need to make the base url a string and replace the me@example.com with the email address and encode it with `encodeURIComponent(uri);`

Comment: You can open the Form and click the 3 vertical dots.  Select _Get pre-filled link_ and fill in the blanks you wish filled in.  You can then "Submit" and get a URL which will pre-fill in the fields with the value you entered.  You do not need to fill in all the fields.  Do note that this exposes the email address and they might change it as well as it does not stop them from doing so unless you fully validate the response to be that email only.

Comment: The only issue is that I'm not looking for it to be a question, I want the confirmation email that gets sent to only get sent to one place. Google has it be an option to collect a users email address but I'm trying to make it so it's always the same user? idk... the answer may be that it's not possible. I've tried using the form add-ons and nothing does exactly what I want. blahhhhhhhhhh haha

Answer (score 1):

IF the email is for a google account, you can log in with that account, open the form and go to **Responses**.  Click the 3 vertical dot icon right above the Accepting responses option and choose **Get email notifications for new responses**.

In one comment you state you have tried using form add-ons.  I know [Email Notifications for Forms](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-notifications-for-f/acknfdkglemcidajjmehljifccmflhkm?hl=en) has been used by many and is well received.  I mention it in case you have not tried this particular add-on.  I do not use this, but use custom script.

There are custom script options available as tutorials or sample code which could send to any email and the address can be in any location in the spreadsheet or hard coded in the script (not recommended).  You could use the code in the [Tutorial: Simple Mail Merge](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) to accomplish your goal. I used this as a base and have had a lot of success.  Using that script, you can send the email to an address in the column after the last form response column.  The only difference from the steps in this tutorial and what you wish is that you will not have the email as part of the form.  Instead, if you have 5 questions, form data will be in columns A through F as there will be an extra column for the timestamp  In cell G1, place this formula:

```
=ARRAYFUNCTION(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,IF(ROW(A1:A)=1, "Email Address", "MYEMAIL@MYCOMAIN.com")))
```

replacing MYEMAIL@MYCOMAIN.com with the one you wish to receive the emails.